# Going to someones profile

Tags: php, mysql

I have this userlist page and i want for users to be able to click the users username and it will send them to there profile page how would i go on doing this ?

This line is where the user clicks the username of a user

`echo "<td class='info'><a href=''>". $people_list['username']."</a></td>";`

Also in my .htaccess i have a code that makes it so i go to users profile all i do is http://www.example.com/username

```
<?php
include 'core/int.php';
include 'includes/head.php';
include 'head.php';
include 'includes/body.php';
include 'body.php';

$people_list="SELECT * FROM users";

$people=mysql_query($people_list);

?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.owner {
    color: orange;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Username</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>

      <?php

     while($people_list=mysql_fetch_assoc($people)){
     echo "<tr>";
     if ($people_list['username'] == KillerDucky1){
      echo "<td>". $people_list['user_id']."</td>";
      echo "<td class='warning'><a class='owner' href=''>". $people_list['username']."</a></td>";
      echo "<td>". $people_list['email']."</td>";
     } else {
          echo "<td>". $people_list['user_id']."</td>";
          echo "<td class='info'><a href=''>". $people_list['username']."</a></td>";
           echo "<td>". $people_list['email']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";     
     }
     }     
      ?>
      </thead>
      </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so this means `http://www.yourdomain.com/KillerDucky1` is already working?

Comment: @Ghost Yes what im trying to say is i have userlist that shows everyone in the database so what i want to do is when i click on the persons name it will take me to there profile page

Comment: Just put the username in the `a` link right? -> `<a href='/".$people_list['username']."'>` ?

Comment: then concatenate the username, check Darren's

Comment: @KillerDucky1 There you go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to put the username in the `<a>` link tag :)

```
<a href='/".$people_list['username']."'>...</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try just adding the username to the `href` of the anchor.

```
echo '<td class="info"><a href="/'. $people_list['username'] .'">'. $people_list['username'].'</a></td>';
```

should give you something like:

```
<td class="info"><a href="/username">username</a></td>
```